# Model selection in ensembles

Tags: model-selection, ensemble-learning

I'm trying to build an ensemble for a ML problem where fast prediction time is critical. So I'm interested in keeping my set of level-0 models for the ensemble pruned.

Which measures can I use to select a set of useful and diverse models for my ensemble?

More specifically, I know that models that make different errors would e.g exhibit a low correlation on their predictions. However, two near-perfect models would necessarily be highly-correlated (as they both have to agree a lot to attain high accuracies)

Is there a way to normalize for accuracy in this?

In my head it seems like there should be a smart way of doing this - only considering FNs/FPs of both models, some way of using Jaccard coefficient...